# How to decompose an exponent?

Tags: exponentiation

If i have an function:

$$f(x) = x^a$$

after, i solved an equation:

$$1/x^{an}$$

so, how i can decompose the exponent to get the equation based on my previous function

$$f(x) * x^n$$

this is a error, because $$x^a *x^n = x^{a+n}$$

But i need, $$x^{an}$$

finally, i want decompose the exponent of my solved equation, to work with the equation based on the function $$f(x) = x^a$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\frac{1}{x^{an}} = \frac{1}{(x^a)^n} = \frac{1}{f(x)^n}.
$$